# Ganache Cli private network, all ethers on the network go to 0 after a while

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ganache

I create a ganache cli and initialize my accounts to have ethers using

```
ganache-cli -h "159.89.119.189" -a 3 -e "1000000000000000000000000000" --secure -u 0 -u 1 -u 2 -s 20
```

but after a couple of minutes, all accounts on the network are 0. I'm not able to run any transactions or call contracts again.

A DApp i created connects to this private network This is my app.js

```
App = {
web3Provider: null,
contracts: {},
account: 0x0,
coinbase: 0x0,
coinbase_amount: 0,
loading: false,

init: function () {
    return App.initWeb3();
},


initWeb3: function () {
    // initialize web3
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        //reuse the provider of the Web3 object injected by Metamask
        App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
        //create a new provider and plug it directly into our local node
        //App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
        App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://159.89.119.189:8545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    App.getCoinbase();

    return App.initContract();
},

hostname: function () {
    return window.location.origin;
},

setAccount: function (address) {
    App.account = address;
},

displayAccountInfo: function () {
    // console.log(App);
    if (App.account != 0) {
        toastr.remove();
        toastr.info('Getting Account Info', {timeOut: 300000});
        $('#account').text(App.account);
        App.getBalance();
    }
},

getBalance: function() {
    web3.eth.getBalance(App.account, function (err, balance) {
        if (err === null) {
            if(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") == 0){
                setTimeout(App.getBalance(), 60000);
            } else {
                console.log(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether"));
                toastr.remove();
                $('#accountBalance').text(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
            }
        }
    })
},

getCoinbase: function () {
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function (err, account) {
        if (err === null) {
            App.coinbase = account;
            // $('#account').text(account);
            web3.eth.getBalance(account, function (err, balance) {
                if (err === null) {
                    App.coinbase_amount = web3.fromWei(balance, "ether").toNumber();
                    console.log(App.coinbase, App.coinbase_amount)
                }
            })
        }
    });
},

transfer: function() {
    web3.personal.unlockAccount(App.coinbase, "pass12345", 100000, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result)
        console.log(err)
    web3.personal.unlockAccount(App.account, "pass@123", 100000, function (err, result) {
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from: App.coinbase,
            to: App.account,
            value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")
        }, function (err, result) {
            if (err == null) {
                console.log("sent money");
                console.log(result)
                console.log(err)
                web3.eth.getBalance(App.account, function (err, balance) {
                    if (err === null) {
                        console.log(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    });
    });
},

register: function () {
    let email = $('#inputEmail');
    let fname = $('#inputFname');
    let lname = $('#inputLname');
    let password = $('#inputPassword');
    let btnRegister = $('#btnRegister');
    if (email.val() == "" || fname.val() == "" || lname.val() == "" || password.val() == "") {
        toastr.error('Please fill all fields');
        return false;
    }
    btnRegister.attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    web3.personal.newAccount("pass@123", function (err, data) {
        let address = data;
        if (err === null) {
            let postData = {
                email: email.val(),
                fname: fname.val(),
                lname: lname.val(),
                password: password.val(),
                address: data
            }
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: App.hostname() + "/register",
                data: postData,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    if (data.status == "success") {
                        web3.personal.unlockAccount(address, "pass@123", 1000, function (err, result) {
                            web3.eth.sendTransaction({
                                from: App.coinbase,
                                to: address,
                                value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")
                            }, function (err, result) {
                                if (err == null) {
                                    console.log("sent money");
                                    console.log(result)
                                    web3.eth.getBalance(App.coinbase, function (err, balance) {
                                        if (err === null) {
                                            console.log("coinbase "+web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
                                        }
                                    })
                                    web3.eth.getBalance(address, function (err, balance) {
                                        if (err === null) {
                                            console.log(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                                else {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                                toastr.success("Success.");
                                window.location.href = App.hostname();
                            })
                        });
                    } else {
                        toastr.error(data.data);
                    }
                    btnRegister.attr("disabled", false);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    toastr.error('Error Registering');
                    btnRegister.attr("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        } else {
            toastr.error('Error Registering');
            btnRegister.attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        }
    })
},

login: function () {
    let email = $('#inputEmail');
    let password = $('#inputPassword');
    let btnLogin = $('#btnLogin');
    if (email.val() == "" || password.val() == "") {
        toastr.error('Please fill all fields');
        return false;
    }
    btnLogin.attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    let postData = {
        email: email.val(),
        password: password.val(),
    }
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: App.hostname() + "/login",
        data: postData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data.status == "success") {
                toastr.success("Success.");
                window.location.href = App.hostname();
            } else {
                toastr.error(data.data);
            }
            btnLogin.attr("disabled", false);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            toastr.error('Error Registering');
            btnLogin.attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
},

initContract: function () {
    $.getJSON('Chainlist.json', function (chainListArtifact) {
        // get the contract artifact file and use it to instantiate a truffle contract abstraction
        App.contracts.ChainList = TruffleContract(chainListArtifact);
        // set the provider for our contracts
        App.contracts.ChainList.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
        // listen to events
        App.listenToEvents();
        // retrieve the article from the contract
        return App.reloadArticles();
    });
},

reloadArticles: function () {
    // avoid re-entry
    if (App.loading) {
        return
    }
    App.loading = true
    // refresh account information because the balance might have changed
    App.displayAccountInfo();

    var chainListInstance;

    App.contracts.ChainList.deployed().then(function (instance) {
        chainListInstance = instance;
        return chainListInstance.getArticlesForSale();
    }).then(function (articleIds) {
        $('#articlesRow').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < articleIds.length; i++) {
            var articleID = articleIds[i];
            chainListInstance.articles(articleID.toNumber())
                .then(function (article) {
                    App.displayArticle(article[0], article[1], article[3], article[4], article[5], article[6])
                });
        }

        App.loading = false;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        App.loading = false;
    });
},

sellArticle: function () {
    // retrieve the detail of the article
    var _article_name = $('#article_name').val();
    var _description = $('#article_description').val();
    var _price = web3.toWei(parseFloat($('#article_price').val() || 0), "ether");
    const file = $('#article_image').prop('files')[0];

    if ((_article_name.trim() == '') || (_price == 0)) {
        // nothing to sell
        return false;
    }

    const name = (+new Date()) + '-' + file.name;
    const metadata = {
        contentType: file.type
    };
    let ref = firebase.storage().ref();
    const task = ref.child(name).put(file, metadata);
    toastr.info('Processing.....', {timeOut: 30000});
    task.then((snapshot) => {
        const _image_url = snapshot.downloadURL;
        console.log(_image_url);
        web3.personal.unlockAccount(App.account, "pass@123", 1000, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(err);
            App.contracts.ChainList.deployed().then(function (instance) {
                return instance.sellArticle(_article_name, _description, _price, _image_url, {
                    from: App.account,
                    gas: 500000
                });
            }).then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $('#article_name').val("");
                $('#article_description').val("");
                $('#article_price').val("");
                $('#article_image').val("");
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });


},

displayArticle: function (id, seller, name, description, price, image_url) {
    var articlesRow = $('#articlesRow');
    var etherPrice = web3.fromWei(price, "ether");
    // retrieve the article template and fill it
    var articleTemplate = $('#articleTemplate');
    articleTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(name);
    articleTemplate.find('.article-description').text(description);
    articleTemplate.find('.article-price').text(etherPrice);
    articleTemplate.find('.btn-image-url').attr('href', image_url);
    articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').attr('data-value', etherPrice);
    articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').attr('data-id', id);

    if (seller == App.account) {
        articleTemplate.find('.article-seller').text("You");
        articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').hide();
    } else {
        articleTemplate.find('.article-seller').text(seller);
        articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').show();
    }
    // buyer
    // var buyer = article[1];
    // if (buyer == App.account) {
    //   buyer = "You";
    // } else if (buyer == 0x0){
    //  buyer = "None yet"
    // }
    // articleTemplate.find('.article-buyer').text(buyer);
    // add this article
    toastr.clear();
    $('#articlesRow').append(articleTemplate.html());
},

// listen to events triggered by the contract
listenToEvents: function () {
    App.contracts.ChainList.deployed().then(function (instance) {
        instance.LogSellArticle({}, {}).watch(function (error, event) {
            if (!error) {
                $("#events").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + event.args._name + ' is now for sale</li>');
            } else {
                console.error(error);
            }
            App.reloadArticles();
        });

        instance.LogBuyArticle({}, {}).watch(function (error, event) {
            if (!error) {
                $('#sellBtn').attr("disabled", false);
                $("#events").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + event.args._buyer + ' bought ' + event.args._name + '</li>');
            } else {
                console.error(error);
            }
            App.reloadArticles();
        });
    });
},

// retrieve article price from data-value and process buyArticle function
buyArticle: function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    // retrieve article Price
    toastr.info('Processing.....', {timeOut: 30000});
    $(event.target).attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    $('#sellBtn').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    var price = parseFloat($(event.target).data('value'));
    var articleID = parseFloat($(event.target).data('id'));

    web3.personal.unlockAccount(App.account, "pass@123", 1000, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(err);
        App.contracts.ChainList.deployed().then(function (instance) {
            return instance.buyArticle(articleID, {
                from: App.account,
                value: web3.toWei(price, "ether"),
                gas: 500000
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            })
        });
    });
}

};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyAQp34HzZS_3xckuxcVcsUWgCu8_p7UzxA",
          authDomain: "comflo-1518513183870.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://comflo-1518513183870.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "comflo-1518513183870",
          storageBucket: "comflo-1518513183870.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "798445619042"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
  });
});
```

Same thing happens when i run a geth private server. I'm using a node app with express.

Comment: Is your node in a public accessible computer? Perhaps someone is erroneously trying to drain your node thinking it is on mainnet.

Comment: I'm running the node on an ubuntu server 
How do i make certain of this security

Comment: Ganache is used to develop locally and doesn't have extra protections. You can put it behind a password protected proxy like nginx, or connect through a ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

using ganache node package and set the ganache mnemonic and default balance will ensure the same accounts for each launch, then using metamask transfer 999 eth from wallets 1 through 9 to wallet 0.

```
const ganache = require('ganache');

const options = {
 namespace: { 
  option: "chain,database,fork,logging,miner,wallet,personal"
 },
 chain: {
  chainId: 1337,
  networkId: 1
 },
 logging: {
  verbose: true
 },
 wallet: {
  accountKeysPath: path.join(os.homedir(),"wallets.json"),
  mnemonic: "some mnemonic fixed sentence",
  maximum_wallets: 10,
  defaultBalance: 1000
 },
 db_path: os.homedir()
};
 
const server = ganache.server(options);
server.listen(8545,async err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`ganache listening on port ${PORT}...`);
  provider = server.provider;
  accounts = await provider.request({
     method: "eth_accounts",
     params: []
  });
  console.log(accounts);  
});
```

Your wallet addresses with private keys are save in the wallet.json file located in your user home directory.